# Network adapter missing in Ubuntu 18.04 after migration from VirtualBox to Hyper-V

Tags: ubuntu, hyper-v

When I started my VirtualBox instances I planned ahead and used vhd drive files.  Creating a new instance in Hyper-v using the drive has been painless and my main instance is booting up but has no network connection.  I tried adding a legacy network adapter but that isn't working either, however it does show as being detected.  The Ubuntu installer sees the device just fine at setup so there has to be a way to get it installed or something.  I'm not a Linux guru and am having a hard time finding an answer online or from my Linux friends.

Ubuntu Server 18.04

Please help.

Comment: So are you using Hyper-V or VirtualBox, they are incompatible with one another, and if you are using Hyper-V what is your host os?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 18.04 uses `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml` for network configuration instead of `/etc/network/interfaces`

If Ubuntu is installed into VirtualBox, the interface listed in `50-cloud-init.yaml` is a weird name like `enp0s3`.  Hyper-V uses a standard `eth0` or something.  I don't really know the technicalities of it, but when I changed it to say `eth0`, it started working after a reboot.

The file looks like this:

```
network:
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            addresses: []
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true
    version: 2
```